# How do I print the 1st word of each line in a txt file?

Tags: python, file, split, line

I'm trying to write some code that reads a text file and prints the 1st letter of each line. My current code is:

```
f=open("testfile1.txt","r")

for line in f:
    words=line.split()
    print(words[0])
```

With this, the strings should be split into the individual words, but when I run the code, I get an error message saying list index out of range. I have tried the solutions of similar questions people had on the same topic, but when I use the same code, I get this error. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: You mean first letter or first word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like there are empty lines, so the below should work:

```
f=open("testfile1.txt","r")

for line in f:
    words=line.split()
    if words:
        print(words[0])
f.close()
```

Even better, `with open`:

```
with open("testfile1.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        if words:
            print(words[0])
```

Comment: @SeungminHong Please read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The errors sound like there are empty lines in the file. You just need to detect them.Also, in python there's a handy trick to iterate over the lines of a file! This can be done as follows.

```py
# in python the default file mode is "r", or read.
with open("testfile1.txt") as r:
    for line in r:
        # detect empty lines with python's default boolean values
        if line:
            print(line.split()[0])
```